# Como alterar o nome padrão de uma coluna do eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou em um projeto que está em produção, e por padrão quando usamos uma chave estrangeira no eloquent seguimos a seguinte regra "user_id" por exemplo para armazenar o id do usuário.

Só que no banco que estou trabalhando colocaram este campo como "`id_user`" e sempre vou fazer o relacionamento gera um erro dizendo que o campo "`user_id`" não foi encontrado. Como posso fazer que meu código entenda que o `user_id` é o `id_user` no meu banco?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você declara o relacionamento entre os `models` você tem o segundo e terceiro parâmetro da função de relacionamento para realizar esta alteração dessa convenção, por exemplo:

```
public function address() {
    return $this->hasMany('user', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```